# How should I denote "undefined" in a functions definition

Tags: limits, notation

While solving some limits, I thought this might be a nice strategy.

$$
 \lim_{x \to -2} \frac{x^2-4}{x^2+3x+2} = \lim_{x \to -2} f(x) \\
 f(x) = \frac{(x-2)(x+2)}{(x+2)(x+1)} =
  \begin{cases}
   \frac{x-2}{x+1},& x \neq -2 \\
   \varnothing,& x = -2
  \end{cases} \\
 \lim_{x \to -2} f(x) = \frac{-2-2}{-2+1}=\frac{-4}{-1}=4
$$

First, you define an equivalent function to the one given, isolating the any undefined points/ranges and then finding the limits for the defined parts.

My question is - how should I mathematically denote the value for undefined points/ranges in the equivalent function? Here, I wrote $\varnothing$ as in there is no result, the result is an empty set, but I'm not sure this is appropriate.

#### Edit 1

I do realise this comes naturally

$$f(x)=\frac{x-2}{x+1}\;,\;\;x\neq -2$$

But isn't there a loss of information as a result? Whereby you can't determine just by this definition, whether it has a value at $-2$. That's just my intuition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the most usual writing would be

$$f(x)=\frac{x-2}{x+1}\;,\;\;x\neq -2$$

as simple as that, and it is enough to comfortable evaluate the limit, which you correctly did.

Comment: I totally understand this, bus say in situations not as trivial, such as the function having multiple undefined points, how should I denote the value for $x=-2$, as in this case?

Comment: Also, your statement doesn't imply any value at the point $x=-2$, so isn't there an information loss?

Comment: You just take those points *out* of the definition domain, @MorganWilde, no matter how many of them are there. And of course my statement implies there's no value of the **original** function at $\;x=-2\;$ : the function isn't defined there!

Comment: Oooh, got it now :). Sure, this does make perfect sense. Thanks @DonAntonio!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to.  This is all you need to write.

$$\lim_{x \to -2} \frac{x^2 - 4}{x^2 + 3x + 2} = \lim_{x \to -2} \frac{(x-2)(x+2)}{(x+1)(x+2)} = \lim_{x \to -2} \frac{x-2}{x+1} = \frac{-4}{-1}=4.$$

The point is, the functions $\frac{x^2 - 4}{x^2 + 3x + 2}$ and $\frac{x-2}{x+1}$ are not the same function, as the first is undefined at $-2$ and the second is not.  But, the limits of the two functions are the same so what I wrote is perfectly correct.

Comment: This may sound too meta, but how do I know they're both the same if what I'm doing is calculating it? Sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: This is a standard theorem in every calculus book.  If you are taking the limit as $x \to a$ of two functions that are exactly the same except at one point $b$ (which could be $a$ or not $a$), and if the limit of one of the two functions exists and is $L$, then you automatically know that the limit of the other function exists and is also $L$.